# what types of the changes i have to do if i m going to make app for android tablets from existing app of android mob?

Tags: android

what types of the changes i have to do if i m going to make app for android tablets from existing app of android mob??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got [this one](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/galaxyTab.do) from Samsung, it talks about developing for their Galaxy Tab. Hope it can help.